# The set of all conjugation classes of group $G$ form a partition of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So the property I would like to proof is the same as stated in the title:

Consider the group $G,\cdot$. The set of all conjugation classes of group $G$ form a partition of $G$

So to prove this, one needs to show that the union of conjugation classes of $G$ is equal to the group $G$. And that two different conjugation classes are disjunct. But I don't know how to proof both parts.

Comment: For equality, are you struggling with the union of conjugacy classes is contained in $G$ or $G$ is contained in the union of conjugacy classes? For disjoint, if $A$ and $B$ are conjugacy classes and $x\in A\cap B$ then can you define $A$ and $B$ in terms of $x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $g\in G$, then $g$ belongs to the conjugation class $[g]$ of $g$. Therefore, $G=\bigcup_{g\in G}[g]$.

And if $[g_1]\cap[g_2]\neq\emptyset$, take $g\in[g_1]\cap[g_2]$. Then there are $h_1,h_2\in G$ such that $g=h_1g_1{h_1}^{-1}$ and that $g=h_2g_2{h_2}^{-1}$. But then\begin{align}g_1&={h_1}^{-1}gh_1\\&={h_1}^{-1}{h_2}g_2{h_2}^{-1}h_1\\&=({h_2}^{-1}h_1)^{-1}g_2({h_2}^{-1}h_1)\end{align}and so $[g_1]=[g_2]$.

Comment: For some reason, I always find not so straightforward that $g_1\in [g_2]$ "and so" $[g_1]=[g_2]$, I mean without mentioning the surjectivity of the map $G\to G$, $g\mapsto \tilde gg$, for any given $\tilde g\in G$. But maybe I'm just overthinking.

Comment: @user750041If $g_1\in[g_2]$, there is an element $h$ of $G$ such that $g_1=h^{-1}g_2h$. So, if $g\in[g_1]$ and if $j\in G$ is such that $g=j^{-1}g_1j$, we have$$g=j^{-1}h^{-1}g_2hj=(hj)^{-1}g_2(hj)$$and therefore $g\in[g_2]$. This proves that $[g_1]\subset[g_2]$ and, by symmetry, $[g_2]\subset[g_1]$. No need to mention that that map is surjective.

Comment: Yes, that's an equivalent way to elaborate the "and so".

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You can prove this by showing that the relation $\sim$ on $G$ defined by:$$g\sim h\iff \exists x\in G\;[gx=xh]$$is an equivalence relation.

The equivalence classes (they form a partition of $G$) are exactly the conjugation classes.